# Springboot : Dependency injection in the filter does not work

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am working on a springboot application. This contains multiple filters. For one of the newly introduced filter, I want to inject a bean.However I am getting following error while trying to inject the bean:

Method threw 'java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException' exception. Cannot evaluate com.test.api.filter.RContext$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4bbc6342.toString()

**Filter:**

```
@Component
public class ContextFilter implements Filter {
    private final static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ContextFilter.class);

    @Autowired
    RContext rContext;

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        LOG.info("Processing context filter");
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        LOG.info("Start..", 
        rContext.setContextData("Test data");
        LOG.info("Done..", req.getRequestURI());
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }
}
```

**RContext class:**

```
@Scope(value="request", proxyMode= ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class RContext {

    String user;
    String contextData;
    String activeProfile;

    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getContextData() {
        return contextData;
    }

    public void setContextData(String contextData) {
        this.contextData = contextData;
    }

    public String getActiveProfile() {
        return activeProfile;
    }

    public void setActiveProfile(String activeProfile) {
        this.activeProfile = activeProfile;
    }
}
```

Comment: could you try to just use "@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)" on context? and ADD "@Component"!- the question why u want to autowire this simple bean. (there are many other flaws in this code - but not in scope of this problem)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response. This change worked for me. However I wanted to keep the scope as 'request' as the validity of the data is per request. Regarding your question, We have a common API which is being used by two clients currently. ContextId is something which is very specific to clent A and was introduced due to some technical limitations. We dont want to change all our APIs to receive this specific parameter as its not a standard parameter and we dont want other clients to get confused with this.

Comment: For this specific use case json views exist. You can make specific fields visible only to some clients/ views.

Comment: The value is not part of message body. its a request parameter. My first plan was to make the parameter optional but in this way we will have to touch all our existing APIs (as we need to introduce this new parameter which does not make any sense for other clients). Then the second approach, where I thought to extract this information and populate the bean injected --> update the URI to match with existing end point uri. While following the second approach I faced this issue.Gradually it appears that this approach is more complex and I may need to fallback to first one.

Answer (score 0):

If you could annotate the RContext class with @Service, then the following solution might work in the doFilter method:

```
RContext rContext;

ServletContext servletContext = request.getServletContext();
WebApplicationContext wac = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
rContext = wac.getBean(RContext.class);
```